# Clistctrl item text color

Tags: mfc, clistctrl

How do you change the text color of a Clistctrl item (report view)?

Answer (score 11):

You need to handle the [NM_CUSTOMDRAW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774865(VS.85).aspx) message and change the text color in that handler.

For an example, see [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/lvcustomdraw.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I would implement a `CMFCListCtrl` derived class and override the `OnGetCellTextColor` method. Things are much easier this way than with custom draws.