# Change Background color of full column of CListCtrl in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc, clistctrl

Ive made a CListCtrl in Report View in MFC.
I want to color the first column (the full column, not only those cells where an Item is) with a grey background.

How can I do this?
Thank

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/19682479/385646

Comment: I would implement a `CMFCLisCtrl` derived class and override the `OnGetCellBkColor` method. Things are much easier this way than with custom draws. I had this as an answer here, but some moderator delete it, because he/she considered it is equal to the answer I provided on http://stackoverflow.com/a/37571685/383779 `OnGetCellBkColor` and `OnGetCellTextColor` are different things! **WHATEVER!**

Answer (score 0):

The way you will implement this is color each cell of the first row individually. The code will look something like below, which basically a blue print but It should work (Note:I haven't test this for this post). You will have to use `lplvcd->iSubItem` and paint the first column of each row.

```
void MyList::OnNMCustomdraw(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    NMLVCUSTOMDRAW* cd = reinterpret_cast<NMLVCUSTOMDRAW*>(pNMHDR);

    *pResult = CDRF_DODEFAULT;

    switch( cd->nmcd.dwDrawStage)
    {
        case CDDS_PREPAINT:
            *pResult = CDRF_NOTIFYITEMDRAW;
            break;

        case CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT:
            {
                int rowNumber = cd->nmcd.dwItemSpec;
                bool highlightRow = (bool)GetItemData(rowNumber);
                if (highlightRow)
                {
                    COLORREF backgroundColor;
                    backgroundColor = RGB(255, 0, 0);
                    cd->clrTextBk = backgroundColor;
                }
            }
            break;
        case CDDS_SUBITEM | CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT:
            {

                // something like if(lplvcd->iSubItem == 0 ) to paint first column
                lplvcd->clrText = RGB(0,0,255);


                *pResult = CDRF_NEWFONT;
                return;
            }

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here two perfect articles that describe custom draw in detail.

[Part I](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/controls/listview/customdrawing/article.php/c4195/Custom-Draw-ListView-Controls-Part-I.htm) & [Part II](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/controls/listview/customdrawing/article.php/c4199/Custom-Draw-ListView-Controls-Part-II.htm)